# Is it possible to commit changes in two working directories (in the same repository) in the same commit?

Tags: svn

I work against a repository that has a large number of projects. Because of this, I only check out single projects in my development environment. Now I've made inter-connected changes in two of these projects. So naturally, they should be in the same commit. Is this possible without checking out the entire SVN repository?

Example repository structure:

```
svn.example.com/huge-repository/
    project-1/
    ...
    project-101/
```

Example working development structure:

```
~/src/
    project-5/
    project-42/
```

I want to commit changes to both `project-5` and `project-42` in one commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a [sparse working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) that only contains the relevant files.  This will enable you to make one commit without having to check out the entire repository.

Example:

```
svn checkout http://svn.example.com/huge-repository --depth empty
cd huge-repository
svn update project-5
svn update project-42
```

You can even use `--depth empty` on `svn update` to cherry-pick individual files or subdirectories, but by default it will get the entire folder (`--depth infinity`).